# Android studio code completion doesnt include variables name

Tags: android, android-studio, code-completion

I have been following some online tutorial to learn android and so far so good. However, in the tutorial when a method is imported using ctrl+space the arguments which the method takes are readable.

Example when using the auto complete to create a new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() it shows the arguments in a readable form.

```
 myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

When i try the exact same thing i get the code imported but the arguments names i get are different.

Any idea how would i get the code imported using auto complete to show more readable arguments.

```
 myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is literally the same thing. Depending on the version of android studio and SDK it might name them differently. I understand that this might seem confusing when you are a newbie but what matters is the arguments passed and not how they are named. You ultimately get similar values regardless of how the arguments are named. For example int position and int i will be equal to the same value. If its such a big deal to you you can rename them.